# Proving positive definite of a specific matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A = D + L + L^T $, where D is the diagonal of $A$ and L is the lower triangular matrix, is symmetric and positive definite, then:

$$ M_\omega= \left(\frac{1}{\omega}D + L\right) \frac{\omega}{2-\omega}
D^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{\omega} D+ L^T \right) $$

is also symmetric and positive definite $\forall \omega \in (0,2)$.

I haven't any problems proving that $M_\omega$ is symmetric:

$$(M_\omega)^{T} = \left( \frac{1}{\omega} D + L^{T}\right)^{T} \frac{\omega}{2- \omega} D^{-T} \left( \frac{1}{\omega} D + L \right)^{T} = \left( \frac{1}{\omega} D +L \right) \frac{\omega}{2-\omega} D^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\omega} D+ L^{T} \right) = M_\omega$$

But I'm stuck whit the prove of positive definite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me denote
$$
L_\omega:= L + \frac1\omega D,
$$
which is invertible.
Then
$$
M_\omega = L_\omega \left(\frac\omega{2-\omega} D^{-1}\right) L_\omega^T.
$$
If $0<\omega<2$, then $\frac\omega{2-\omega}>0$, hence $\frac\omega{2-\omega} D^{-1}$ is positive definite with smallest positive eigenvalue $\lambda>0$. (The diagonal of a symmetric positive matrix is positive, hence $D^{-1}$ is positiv definite.)

Then $M_\omega$ is positive definite as well. Let $x\ne0$. Then
$$
x^TM_\omega x = (L_\omega^Tx)^T \left(\frac\omega{2-\omega} D^{-1}\right) (L_\omega^Tx) \ge \lambda \|L_\omega^Tx\|^2 >0,
$$
as $L_\omega^Tx\ne0$.